# How do I water my full grown cherry tree?

Tags: trees, watering, cherries

I bought a house three years ago, the cherry trees appeared to be fruitless. This year they flowered and now have cherries all over them. They are very large adult trees.

- Do I water them?
- How often and in what way do I water them?
- Do I spray the ground around them?
- Do I dig a little ring around them in the dirt?
- Do I just leave them alone.

I want to get the cherries and not destroy them. I live in northern California, just above Sonora at around 3000 feet.

Answer (score 2):

Cherry trees take at  least 3-4 years to blossom, might explain why you are just getting them.  I know some plants will also lay dormant for a number of seasons usually weather based. You should not have to water your full grown cherry tree in the spring, sometimes you do not need to at all. If you go any extended period of time in the middle of summer with no rain you may choose to. As far as where to water. Cherry trees have shallow roots that extend a large diameter. You do not want to water right on the base for this reason. The root tips grow away from the base around 60-80% of the growth from the trees height roughly. If in following years by chance you are not getting a lot of rain when the cherries start to blossom you will want to water it then, because they need additional water to fill the cherries.